# Why does VScode delete code permanently when working remotely?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Question's in the title.
I got me curious  since, when working locally, deleting files sends them to the trash bin.

When working remotely, is there no way to send a file to either the local or the remote trash bin?

Is there a technical reason this basic feature is missing, or is it just a feature not implemented yet?

Comment: I'm not sure how VS works exactly in "remote" mode, but generally speaking, "trash bins" are an implementation detail of the file system and/or OS. A properly abstracted remote connection won't know such details. If you were able to move to a remote trash bin, you'd also need some way to empty that bin remotely, or you risk the file system filling up. To move a remote file to the local trash bin, you'd need to download it to your local system, which may be exactly what you don't want and why you're using remote in the first place. Just expect "delete" to delete. Recoverability is a bonus.

Comment: Have you got any solutions yet?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @Arun Seems like the behavior is by design. I couldn't find any way around it